# C - Segmentation fault

Tags: c

Here's is my little C snippet that generates segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int checkTiime(char time[]);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char time1[6];
    char time2[6];

    printf("Tempo 1 [hh:mm]: ");
    fgets(time1, sizeof time1, stdin);
    printf("Tempo 2 [hh:mm]: ");
    fgets(time2, sizeof time2, stdin);

    printf("Checktime: %d", checkTime(time1));

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int checkTime(char time[]){

    long hours = 0;
    long minutes = 0;

    if(time[2] == ':') {

        if(isdigit(time[3]) && isdigit(time[4]) && isdigit(time[0]) && isdigit(time[1])) {
            hours = strtol(time[0], NULL, 10) + strtol(time[1], NULL, 10);
            minutes = strtol(time[3], NULL, 10) + strtol(time[4], NULL, 10);

            if((hours >= 0 && hours <= 23) && (minutes >= 0 && minutes <= 59)){

                return 0;

            } else {

                return 1;

            }

        } else {

            return 1;

        } 

    } else {

        return 1;

    }

}
```

Can someone help me. I really don't know why is giving my problems.

I also noticed that when i enter, for example, "12:34" it asks me to enter the second  input, but when i write "12:34" then i delete "34" using backspace and enter "34" again it writes the second printf but doesn't allow me enter the second input and the program exits.

**Personal comment:**

I noticed that it's better to use `gets()` function to input strings beacause it doesn't count the `\n` character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful when using `fgets`. Your calls require it to read in at most 6 characters before it hits either a newline or EOF. `fgets` considers the newline character to be a valid character and stores it too, if one such is encountered. Now, in your case, the last character is not a NULL as it should in C-style strings but a `\n`. You need to replace it by a `NULL` before you can pass it to `strtol` which expects a C-style NULL terminated string. So:

```
if (fgets(time1, sizeof time1, stdin) != NULL) {
    time1[ sizeof time1 - 1 ] = NULL;
}
```

Or, even better:

```
if (fgets(time1, sizeof time1 - 1, stdin) != NULL) {
    // hurray we have the time!
}
```

Or, you can have your own newline-safe `fgets` wrapper:

```
char *chomp(char *buf, size_t sz, FILE *fp, size_t *outsz) {
   char *p = fgets(buf, sz - 1, fp) ; /* make sure there is room for terminating NULL */
   if (p != NULL) {
      char *nl = strchr(buf, '\n');
      if (nl) *nl = NULL; /* replace trailing newline */
      *outsz = strlen(buf); /* recompute */
   }
   return p;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Anyway i just solved my problem using `gets()` function and buy splitting time into 2 strings containing hours and minutes.

Comment: `gets` is dangerous. Don't use it. Learn how to use `fgets` or `scanf`.